# JDBC does not recognize custom type-safe wrapper for fields

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to implement a wrapper class for my ID fields from my database to improve typesafety - something like this: http://principles-wiki.net/patterns:type-safe_wrapper

I've run into problems when using these as parameters to preparedstatements. I'm using ActiveJDBC but I think the problem lies at a lower level, with JDBC.

For example, the following (artificial) line produces an exception:

```
ModelDelegate.count(PSetAnswer::class.java, "psetproblemid in (?)", new PSetProblemId(333661));
```

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: java.sql.SQLException: Type com.ktbyte.dto.id.PSetProblemId not supported type, query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM psetanswers WHERE psetproblemid in (?), params: 333661
    at [...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Type com.ktbyte.dto.id.PSetProblemId not supported type
    at [...]
```

My ID classes look like this:

```java
public class PSetProblemId extends Id.IntId {
    public PSetProblemId(Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

abstract public class Id<T> {
    public final T value;

    public Id(T value) {
        this.value = requireNonNull(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }

    [...]

    public static abstract class IntId extends Id<Integer> {
        public IntId(Integer value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell digging through stacktraces, our JDBC driver (MariaDB) has a `Configuration` which includes an array of `Codecs` that describe how to convert a Java class to a particular type:

```java
// deep in org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePreparedStatement
for (Codec<?> codec : con.getContext().getConf().codecs()) {
  if (codec.canEncode(x)) {
    Parameter p = new Parameter(codec, x, scaleOrLength);
    parameters.set(parameterIndex - 1, p);
    return;
  }
}

throw new SQLException(String.format("Type %s not supported type", x.getClass().getName()));
```

I think what I need is to add a Codec that describes how to convert an IntId sub-class to an integer to my JDBC configuration. If so, how do I do that? Or is there another way to solve this?

edit: Just tried making `Id` `implements RowId`, but this didn't help. Same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC doesn't support any of this. It is a *very* low level API that *can* be used as a direct API (as in, an API used by folks writing apps that interact with DBs), but you really shouldn't. It's best seen as a meta-API: An API used by folks writing **database APIs** - you write a layer 'in between'.

Part of the problem is that JDBC must cater to three things which combine to make things rather annoying:

- It's incredibly old API. Not by itself a problem, but it can't change with the times; not with new ideas about how APIs should be designed, and not with new ideas about how DBs are supposed to work internally.
- It has to expose as much as it can: Whilst JDBC forces SQL and synchronized access, it doesn't want to force anything else. So if a DB has some exotic feature, JDBC has to make it available to you. If there is some way to interact with the DB that is slightly faster, it has to expose that.
- It has to, of course, cater to every database.

There are lots of obvious faults in the API design as a consequence. For example, `.setDate` is **broken** - the vast majority of databases do things correctly and consider `DATETIME` or `DATE` columns to require storing year+month+day (+hour+minute+second for datetimes), and **not** anything millisecond-since-epoch based; that last one goes completely wrong if the underlying timezone definitions change, which change. All the time (hi, dutchies! Did you know all birthdates prior to 1945 that you store through any process that converts through millis-since-epoch have shifted the birthdate down by a day silently if you upgrade to newer releases of java17 or later if using the `Europe/Amsterdam` timezone? OpenJDK messed up and misunderstood a change to the tzdata definitions! Those DBs that properly store year+month+day are not affected).

`java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, and that is a lying liar of a name, because that represents an instant, as per epoch, and absolutely does not store dates in any way. Hence, JDBC's `.getDate` and `.setDate` methods are bad.

The correct way to set dates is `.setObject(pos, someLocalDateInstance)` and `.getObject(someColIdxOrName, LocalDate.class)` which is very unwieldy, but nevertheless, the only correct way to do it (or `ZonedDateTime` if you are storing a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` style value insteaD).

That's one of about a 100 examples of why JDBC is thoroughly unsuitable.

So, write a library that wraps around it, and add your codecs *there*, if you really want to. Or simply allow any instance whose class implements `DbCodec` or whatnot, which can translate it to a type that JDBC inherently understands (all the primitives, string, LocalDate, ZonedDateTime, and a few others).

Or, don't do that, and use one that was already written. There's [JOOQ](https://jooq.org) as well as [JDBI](https://jdbi.org).

If 'write an intermediate layer' is too much work and 'use these fantastic libraries that do all that for you' isn't acceptable, we dive down to a much, much simpler answer: *What you want is not possible, and you will have to get rid of all these type-safe wrappers*.

Comment: Thanks for the great insights into JDBC! I am using an intermediate library - ActiveJDBC. But my error message came from JDBC so I looked past it. So I should look to ActiveJDBC to unwrap my wrappers, it sounds like.

Comment: Never heard of it :(